# Excel 2016 VBA on Mac - How to set a 'Form' Control Checkbox to 'True'

Tags: macos, excel, checkbox, vba

I'm attempting to set the status of a `Form Control` checkbox to `True` in Excel 2016 on a MAC. I keep getting a run-time error 438 and have tried multiple ways of calling the sheet, the workbook, and the checkboxes but none seem to work.

Here is the code: (Sheet Name: Sheet1)

```
Sub SetCheckboxes()

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Check Box 66").OLEFormat.Object.Value = True

End Sub
```

Comment: That code works for me, as does `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").CheckBoxes("Check Box 66").Value = True`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I think my problem was that the original file was built on a PC and the checkboxes from the PC did not function the same as the checkboxes on the MAC. After adding new checkboxes (from the MAC) the code now works.